# R loop for calling iterated columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to apply an OR statement to three columns in a data frame, and output the response to a new column. The below works as intended:

```
df$Responseto1 <- ifelse(df[1] == "Mentioned" |
 df[13] == "Mentioned" |
 df[25] == "Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not")
```

I need this to loop 11 times, and I'm resigned to type it 11 times, hence the use of a loop. I tried to use the following...

```
for (i in 1:11) {
for (j in 13:23) {
for (k in 25:35) {
df$Responseto[i] <- ifelse(df[i] == "Mentioned" |
df[j] == "Mentioned" |
df[k] == "Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not")
}}}
```

However, I get the following error `` Error in `[.data.frame`(df, j) : object 'j' not found ``

Comment: A few points: (a) When you're looking at a single column `df[[i]]` is safer than `df[i]`. `df[[i]]` extract a single column as a vector, whereas `df[i]` is a 1-column data frame. (b) Your error doesn't make much sense, as `j` is defined. Are you sure you ran all that code at once? (c) `df$Responseto[i]` won't work the way you want - that would be the `i`th element of the `df$Responseto` column. You can't use `$` with variable column names. I think you intend `df[[paste0("Responseto", i)]]`....

Comment: (d) Your nested for loop will run for **every combination** of `i`, `j`, and `k`: `i = 1, j = 13, k = 25`, `i = 1, j = 13, k = 26`, `i = 1, j = 13, k = 27`... Is that what you want? If so, you'll need to store the response for each `i,j,k` combination, not just the `i` as you are. Maybe instead you want to define `j = i + 12` and `k = 1 + 24` and only loop over `i`, if you don't want every single combination. It's not super clear from your question. If you add a few rows of sample data that would help us understand the problem and help you better.

Comment: You can use `dput()` to make some sample data, for example `dput(df[1:3, ])` would give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 3 rows, which should be plenty to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the responses received. I used answers to write:

```
for (i in 1:11) { for (j in i+12) { for (k in i+24) {
df[[paste0("Responseto", i)]] <-
 ifelse(df[[i]] == "Mentioned" |
 df[[j]] == "Mentioned" |
 df[[k]] == "Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not")
}}}
```

As pointed out, selecting all lines before running made this successful.

This worked exactly how I intended it. I hope this answer is useful.